# ubuntu 18.04 Some files do not display emblem in nautilus Extension

Tags: nautilus

I want to make a specific file display an emblem using the `nautilus_file_info_add_emblem()` function.

Some files with certain suffixes can be displayed normally (e.g. txt, doc). However, files with no or infrequent suffixes are not displayed properly.

For example see the screenshot below, where the two files are the same.

[image: example]

Is there a solution?

Answer (score 0):

/usr / share / mime / icons are empty, resulting in the wrong file icon